# Word for "a person who generate bill on computer in shopping mall"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is exact word for "**a person who generate bills on computer in shopping mall**"?

Comment: A shop assistant/ sales assistant? (in British English.) Or, in a supermarket or self-service store , a checkout operator.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you but I want to use it in my software implementation so I need a word which fit in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clerk**

> c: one who works at a sales or service counter
>
> a store clerk
>
> a grocery clerk

The person is often refereed to as **check out clerk**

Check out:

> 3: a counter or area in a store where goods are checked out

Definitions from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)

Clarification: This is American English. I cannot speak for British English.